# How do I find out whether a file is within a directory with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, file-io, node.js

Given two absolute or relative paths, `A` and `B`, I want to find out whether `B` is "inside of" the directory `A`—not just in the directory itself, but potentially in a subdirectory. I'd like to do this without a potentially huge number of `fs.readdir` calls.

For instance, if `A` is `/` and `B` is `/foo/bar/baz`, it should be pretty obvious that `B` is within `A`; the recursive `readdir` approach would be extremely inefficient.

One obvious idea is to convert both paths to absolute form, then check if the string form of `B`'s absolute path starts with the string form of `A`'s. However, there are two problems:

1. How do you convert the relative paths to absolute paths?
2. What about symbolic links and such?

I'll accept answers that make calls to Linux utilities (other than `rm -rf`... which *technically* could be used to solve the problem) or third-party Node libraries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var fs = require('fs');

var a = fs.realpathSync('/home/mak/www'); // /var/www
var b = fs.realpathSync('/var/www/test/index.html');

var b_in_a = b.indexOf(a) == 0;

var a_is_dir = fs.statSync(a).isDirectory();
```

`fs.*Sync` also have asynchronous versions, see [fs module](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html).

`fs.realpathSync` and `fs.statSync`will throw if the path does not exist.

Comment: This may be working code but I don't really consider this an answer because it's not explained at all.

Comment: This can give the wrong answer for a file with the same prefix as the folder. If a = `/var/www` and b = `/var/wwwtwo/index.html`, then it returns true.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest this:

```
const path = require('path')

function isWithin(outer, inner) {
    const rel = path.relative(outer, inner);
    return !rel.startsWith('../') && rel !== '..';
}
```

It uses `path.relative` to compute the path of `inner` relative to `outer`. If it's not contained, the first component of the resulting path will be `..`, so that's what we check for.

Comment: Just to mention, this is also return `true` if outer and inner are equal. 

To eliminate that `&& rel` can be added.

Comment: @DS., please, explain what your code does. Don't let people reverse engineer it pointlessly.

Comment: @DavideCannizzo I added an explanation.